# Reading words from file and storing them in a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, fgets

```
void print(vector<const char*> v) {
    for (vector<const char*>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    vector<const char*> v;
    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen("Text.txt", "r");
    char buffer[100];
    while ((fgets(buffer, 100, infile) != NULL)) {
        if (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
            buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
        v.push_back((const char*)buffer);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    print(v);
return 0;
```

}

So this is what I have so far. At the printf (in the while loop), the words from the file are printed correctly. But the function print (which prints the elements of the vector) shows me only the last word repeated by the number of words from the file. For example, let's say I have this in my file:

```
apple
banana
orange
```

The print function will print:

```
orange
orange
orange
```

Edit: So I managed to get this to work. I made a list of "buffers" and it's working fine now. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: If you use C++ iostreams and `std::string` instead of C APIs, the code will be a single line — and, more importantly, work.

Comment: This is an assigment, I have to use fopen, fgets and fclose.

Comment: Seriously?! That is a **terrible** assignment. Your teacher should feel bad.

Comment: Yeah, I won't tell him that. :D

Comment: You have only one `buffer`, and you push it's address on the `vector` each time, thus you only point to one string (using a `std::vector<std::string>` would make this better)

Comment: @LerulLer Somebody has to. But yes, nobody likes the person in class who criticises the teacher so I understand your point.

Comment: Are you sure you are not taking a C programming class?

Comment: @NathanOliver Pretty sure.

Comment: Is it too late to change classes, or schools, for this? Because you're wasting your time in this class if you're taught that kind of mush, and your intent is to acquire sufficient technical skills for a career as a software developer. This is pathetic. You're not really learning C++ here. This is not a slam against you. I wish I can say that this is an exception, sadly, witnessing the nonstop goober parade in the C++ tag here, over some period of time, this is more like a rule, it seems.

Comment: I can't do anything but try to pass this course so I can finish my studies. I know other languages at a decent level so yeah, I try just to pass this.

Comment: It could be so easy to read your file with [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) as source and `std::vector<std::string>` as target, do the copy with [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with input as [std::istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and output as [std::back_insert_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) and do further manipulation with [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling `push_back` on the same array `buffer`, each time storing the same pointer to its initial element in the vector.

This means, among other things, that no matter what you put into `buffer`, before or after calling `push_back`, the `vector` elements are going to point to it. In your case the result is that you see the last element that you have read, but if you wrote to `buffer` after reading the file, the vector would show that new value.

In order to solve this problem you need to push back *copies* of the buffer, instead of pushing the buffer itself. The preferred approach in C++ would be switching away from `vector<const char*>` to `vector<string>`, because strings make the copying and resource management much easier for you.

If you must use pointers, make `vector` store non-const pointers; otherwise you wouldn't be able to call `delete` on them. Instead of pushing back `buffer` allocate `strlen(buffer)+1` `char`s with `new[]`, and `strcpy` the `buffer` into it before calling `push_back`.

Answer (score 1):

Since an actual answer has already posted, your print() function could use some improvements:

```
void print(vector<const char*> const & v) {
    for (auto const chp : v) {
        cout << chp << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

This version takes a reference instead of copying the whole vector. And because the vector isn't changed by `print()` it's `const`.

Also if you want to iterate over all elements of a container you don't have to manage the iterators manually.